# AVCaptureVideoDataOutput and AVCaptureVideoStabilizationModeCinematic preview lag

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avcapturesession, avcaptureoutput

I have scratched my head for years but no outcome on this. When I have AVCaptureVideoDataOutput set and OpenGLES rendering of frames using AVCaptureVideoStabilizationModeCinematic, there is considerable delay in the preview. The delay is much much less if I use AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer. Has anyone found a workaround for it?